# Inserting a content of the text file into org file

Tags: org-babel

I want to insert a body of my `file.txt` to my org file by doing as below:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell
 cat file.txt
#+END_SRC
```

and pick it up in `#+RESULTS` region and displaying in `LaTeX` as on gray area in monospace.

The problem I'm running into is: `Error (org-babel): Error reading results: (end-of-file)`

When instead the `cat file.txt` I put `echo "1 2 3"`

```
   #+BEGIN_SRC shell
     echo "1 2 3"
   #+END_SRC

   #+RESULTS:
   : 1 2 3
```

I know that my block in general works.

What I don't know?

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens, but I can fix it locally by adding the `:results verbatim` header argument (`:results value` also seems to work):

Comment: `   #+BEGIN_SRC shell :results verbatim`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```org
* foo

#+name: file-contents
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :wrap example :results output :exports both
 cat file.txt
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: file-contents
#+begin_example
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
#+end_example
```

This doesn't do the gray background: that would need some additional work particularly on the LaTeX side, but this is a good first step.

BTW, I like naming my code blocks, but you can leave that out if you want (although my recommendation is that all code blocks should be named).

---

EDIT: Here's a way to give the text a gray background. There are many ways to do that in `LaTeX`. AFAICT, the two most common ones are by using `mdframed` or `tcolorbox` - I searched a bit on the TeX SE and chose the simplest solution that I found: an `mdframed` one.

First thing to do is to install the `mdframed` package. I'm on Fedora where I used this command

```
sudo dnf install texlive-mdframed
```

You have to figure out how to do that in your OS/distro.

Second, create a file `graybgtxt.tex` in the same directory as your Org mode file and add this content to it:

```latex
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{%
  linecolor=white,
  backgroundcolor=gray!20,
}
```

Then any `mdframed` environment in `LaTeX` will get the specified background color.

There are a couple of modifications you have to do to your Org mode file.

First, you have to `include` the `graybgtxt.tex` file, by adding this line at the top:

```org
#+LATEX_HEADER: \include{graybgtxt}
```

Note that you do *not* specify the `.tex` extension: it is implicit.

Second, by default `example-blocks` in Org mode are exported to `verbatim` environments in `LaTeX`, but there is a way to override that, by using a `#+LATEX_ATTRIBUTE:` line before the results (for this to work, it is *crucial* that you name your code block, so that the named result will always be produced in the same place):

```org
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment mdframed
```

That will cause the exporter to export `example-blocks` in Org mode to `mdframed` environments in `LaTeX` (instead of the default `verbatim` ones), which, in conjunction with the included `graybgtxt.tex` file, will make `LaTeX` give the contents of the environment a gray background.

Here's what the whole thing looks like finally:

```org
#+LATEX_HEADER: \include{graybgtxt}

* foo

#+name: file-contents
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :results output :wrap example :exports both
 cat file.txt
#+END_SRC

#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment mdframed
#+RESULTS: file-contents
#+begin_example
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
#+end_example
```

Do `C-c C-e lo` to produce and open the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :results verbatim
     echo "1 2 3"
     cat file.txt
   #+END_SRC
```

produced:

```
#+RESULTS:
     : 1 2 3
     : Hello world!
```

Thanks!